# How to use preceding sibling in xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here i want to Accept button. Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="friend-request no-pad ng-scope" ng-if="notifications.friendInvites.length > 0">
<p class="rem-head mzero small">
<div class="reminder-lst lst-box ng-scope" ng-repeat="friendInvite in notifications.friendInvites | limitTo:limit">
<span class="img-frame img-circle">
<span class="pull-left rem-detail-a">
<a class="pull-left rem-detail-a pzero" href="friend#/friends/friendprofile/b6c70e4f-bfe1-440d-836c-2e8fdc88540e">
<span class="frndact pull-right">
<a class="ignore" ng-click="ignoreNotification(friendInvite, 'friend')" href="javascript:void(0)">
<a class="accept" ng-click="acceptNotification(friendInvite, 'friend')" href="javascript:void(0)">
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle green"></i>
</a>
```

I have tried using below xpath but not working. Can anyone plz help me?

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//a[ng-click='acceptNotification(friendInvite, 'friend')']/preceding-sibling::i[@css='.fa.fa-lg.fa-check-circle.green']").
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `//a[@ng-click='acceptNotification(friendInvite, 'friend')'] ...` (notice the missing `@` in your XPath). Also what specific element did you want to select? Because I'm not seeing what that element is looking at your XPath.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for the 'A' tag of class accept, you can try

```
//i[@class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle green"]/preceding-sibling::a[@class="accept"]
```

or

```
//i[@class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle green"]/preceding-sibling::a[@ng-click="acceptNotification(friendInvite, 'friend')"]
```

a couple of things:

- as TT noted your xpath was missing the @ for the attribute selector
- the sample you posted **is not** a *well formed xml*, expect troubles with xpath if you don't have an xhtml compliant source.
- if you use the second example mind to escape either the " or the ' quotes, if you use it inside another expression